# CollapsingToolbarLayout and ViewPager Scroll not work , not collapse

Tags: android, scroll

I have an AppBarLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout and viewPager.

The problem is that if I have a tab in the viewPager with a recycleview list, the toolbar collapses properly, and the scroll has no problems.

Instead, if in the viewPager tab have another type of layout, such as a relative layout, not scroll.

of course if you use a ScrollView, scroll there but the toolbar does not collapse

This is a set of my Viewpager:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new  ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFrag(new Tab1, "RecycleView with list");
adapter.addFrag(new Tab2, "simple relative layout");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/smooth_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/image_demo"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp" />



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

this is my other xml file
```

How can I do so that collapsing even without the recycle View?
Thanks so much

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >



    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView8" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

How can you solve this?
thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Use NestedScrollView as parent layout of your fragment like this

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
```